# What is the + n for

Tags: algorithm

For this algorithm,

```
Bugs(n)
    if n = 0 generate 5 bugs
    else 
        Bugs(n-2);
        for i ← 1 to n
            generate 1 bug
        Bugs(n-2);
```

The Recurrence relation is: `T(n) = 2T(n-2) + n, T(0) = 5`

Why is there `a +n`?  Is it because their is only one for loop, so if their would be two for loops would it be `+ n^2`?

Comment: Please don't fall under the fallacy of "two for loops = n^2", "one for loop = n". It's the number of iterations that matters, not the number of nested loops.

Comment: But aren't iterations dependent on a loop of some sort?

Comment: it's unclear to me what you meant by "two for loops". If it meant "two nested for loops, each iterating from 1 to n", then yes, it would be "+ n^2".

Comment: *but not all loops have O(n) iterations*. Sometimes it's true, but don't trust that as a rule. You can use the idea to build some "suspicions" and work from there, but that's all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well look at what it does for the n != 0 case:

- It calls Bugs(n-2) - so `T(n-2)` for this part
- It generates n bugs - so `n` assuming "generate 1 bug" is constant
- It calls Bugs(n-2) - so `T(n-2) again`

Total: `2T(n-2) + n`

Comment: Thanks, so what would you change "generate 1 bug" to for it to be n^2?